# TypeTags error in Java JDK10

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm working on cloud endpoint. Everything is working fine when I left it off. But after few month I installed everything again and try to run this project but unable to do that there is some kind of error now. I think it's due to **JDK** version and I didn't confirm. This time I'm using **JDK10**.

Here is error (When I run `mvn clean package`):

`Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.codeTypeTags`

Here is pom file.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.azeem.endpoint</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoint</artifactId>


    <!-- [START properties] -->
    <properties>
        <!-- OBJECTIFY -->
        <objectify.version>5.1.5</objectify.version>
        <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>

        <!-- ENDPOINTS -->
        <endpoints.framework.version>2.0.8</endpoints.framework.version>
        <endpoints.management.version>1.0.4</endpoints.management.version>
        <endpoints.project.id>your-project-id</endpoints.project.id>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <!-- [END properties] -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- GEO HASH -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.alpharogroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgeohash-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END GEO HASH -->

        <!-- [START Objectify_Dependencies] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>${objectify.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [END Objectify_Dependencies] -->

        <!-- ENDPOINTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Parent POM defines ${appengine.sdk.version} (updates frequently). -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.57</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
                    <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can you please let me know what the exact problem is and how can I solve it.

**UPDATE**

I just re run the command with **-e** (`mvn clean package -e`) I'm using windows command prompt.
Here is what I got.

```
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso
rImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.ExceptionIn
InitializerError
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (J
avaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCom
piler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCo
mpilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:
129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso
rImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.jav
a:158)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (J
avaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCom
piler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCo
mpilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:
129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso
rImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleGetter.<clinit> (HandleGetter.java:303)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:374)
    at lombok.core.SpiLoadUtil$1$1.next (SpiLoadUtil.java:111)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.loadAnnotationHandlers (HandlerLibrary.java:1
71)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.load (HandlerLibrary.java:156)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.<init> (JavacTransformer.java:44)
    at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.init (LombokProcessor.java:87)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want (AnnotationProcessor
.java:87)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init (AnnotationProcessor.java:140)
    at lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.init (Annotati
onProcessor.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.
<init> (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:674)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProce
ssors$ProcessorStateIterator.next (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:771)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunP
rocs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:866)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2100 (Ja
vacProcessingEnvironment.java:110)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (Java
cProcessingEnvironment.java:1202)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (J
avacProcessingEnvironment.java:1311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.ja
va:1250)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:928)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java
:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.jav
a:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (J
avaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCom
piler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCo
mpilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:
129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso
rImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass (ClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:566)
    at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass (ShadowClassLoader.java:422)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:291)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$SchroedingerType.getFieldCached (JavacTreeMak
er.java:156)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$TypeTag.typeTag (JavacTreeMaker.java:244)
    at lombok.javac.Javac.<clinit> (Javac.java:155)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleGetter.<clinit> (HandleGetter.java:303)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:374)
    at lombok.core.SpiLoadUtil$1$1.next (SpiLoadUtil.java:111)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.loadAnnotationHandlers (HandlerLibrary.java:1
71)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.load (HandlerLibrary.java:156)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.<init> (JavacTransformer.java:44)
    at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.init (LombokProcessor.java:87)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want (AnnotationProcessor
.java:87)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init (AnnotationProcessor.java:140)
    at lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.init (Annotati
onProcessor.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.
<init> (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:674)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProce
ssors$ProcessorStateIterator.next (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:771)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunP
rocs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:866)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2100 (Ja
vacProcessingEnvironment.java:110)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (Java
cProcessingEnvironment.java:1202)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (J
avacProcessingEnvironment.java:1311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.ja
va:1250)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:928)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java
:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.jav
a:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (J
avaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCom
piler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCo
mpilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:
129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccesso
rImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMetho
dAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Comment: Looking around, this appears to be something related to invoking the compiler programmatically using JDK10.  I don't see anything specific that does that, but you might post the whole stacktrace.  Also, you may wish to update both your version of Guava and appengine-maven-plugin.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel I just re-run the command and see what I got

Comment: The error seems to be missing a "." as the error was in prior JDK's com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags  You may wish to try updating your pom.xml to use the latest compiler plugin.  (Note - I'm still guessing or it would be in the box below.)

Comment: Try doing `mvn dependency:tree` and posting that.  Also, you really should be on a current version of the dependencies if you are going to use JDK10.

Comment: I just installed **JDK8** and build the project after that I switch it back to **JDK10** everything is working fine. I don't know how this happen but it's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objectify has a dependency called Lombok, which currently doesn't work with Java 10. See [this issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1572).

Edit: The faulty dependency is actually jgeohash-core:

```
[INFO] +- de.alpharogroup:jgeohash-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.maxmind.geoip:geoip-api:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.16:compile
```

Comment: Objectify only uses lombok as <provided>, so it must be the generated code. tl;dr; there isn't a work-a-round.

Comment: Furthermore, the version of Objectify in the Q's pom (5.1.5) predates the lombok-ization of Objectify. Which means if something is pulling lombok into the build, it's not Objectify. I don't think it has anything to do with the generated code, I think there's some other dependency in the graph that didn't declare `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: You should be able to safely <exclude> lombok from the <dependency> to make things work.

Comment: Another approach (if you want build on Java 10/11) is to update the lombok dependency to 1.18.4 or later.